# What to use to have graphical view of Spark's memory usage (with YARN)?

Tags: memory, memory-management, apache-spark, monitoring

I was going through one of the [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/SparkSummit/understanding-memory-management-in-spark-for-fun-and-profit) on spark memory management and wanted to know how to get a good graphical picture of executor memory usage (something similar to what was mentioned in presentation), to understand out of memory errors better. Also, what is the best way to analyze off-heap memory usage in spark executors? How to find the amount of off-heap memory usage as a function of time?

I looked into Ganglia but it gives node level metrics. I found it hard to understand executor level memory usage using node level metrics.

Answer (score 3):

I've been thinking about a similar tool!

I think [org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener) is the interface to all the low-level metrics in Apache Spark with `onExecutorMetricsUpdate` being the method to look at when developing a higher-level monitoring tool.

You could also monitor JVM using JMX interface, but it might be too low-level and definitely without the contextual information on how Spark uses the resources.